# Autocomplete TextField in swing

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete

I am doing a small project for restaurant billing.In the billing form when the user enters the item ,i need the list of possible items to be displayed from which the user can select the appropriate item and  all the details of the selected item should be filled in the table. ( just like a super market billing). The items are stored in the database (MySQL) and i am using java swing for user interface

Can anyone please suggest some way for achieving my requirement.Some helpful links as well. ThankYou..

Comment: Possible duplicate? - [How could I implement autocompletion using Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485530/how-could-i-implement-autocompletion-using-swing)

Comment: You may find [Auto complete ComboBox](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) example useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [auto-complete package](http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Swingx](https://swingx.java.net/).Contains extensions to the Swing GUI toolkit, including new and enhanced components that provide functionality commonly required by rich client applications. Highlights include:

Sorting, filtering, highlighting for tables, trees, and lists
Find/search
Auto-completion
Login/authentication framework
TreeTable component
Collapsible panel component
Date picker component
Tip-of-the-Day component