# How can I create a JTextArea with Autocomplete?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, swingx

I want to make a program in which when I write in the JTextArea, but when I write a word, it gives me a suggestion on how to complete it. I tried Swingx's AutoCompleteDecorator, but when I finished a word it wouldn't let me type anymore when I had it set to true in strict mode, and if I had it set to "false" it wouldn't give me any more suggestions afterwards. I used the following function:

AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(textArea, keys, false);

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661877/java-using-keylistener-to-check-if-parenthesis-is-pressed/31665872#31665872) perhaps

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code as [here](https://stackabuse.com/example-adding-autocomplete-to-jtextfield/).

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873748/how-to-show-autocomplete-as-i-type-in-jtextarea) if you want dynamic fields using different key event listeners.

Comment: I used the code exactly as it says and then like this:

TAGSText.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
  
  Autocomplete autoComplete = new Autocomplete(TAGSText, TAGSList);
  TAGSText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(autoComplete);

  TAGSText.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), COMMIT_ACTION);
  TAGSText.getActionMap().put(COMMIT_ACTION, autoComplete.new CommitAction());

But it´s not working

Comment: COMMIT_ACTION is a String "commit"

Comment: I already solved it, it turns out that the code only works if what is in the List starts with lowercase. I don't really understand why

Comment: @shiosaku that's good to hear you can upvote the answer if you like .